# Swift: Accept a closure with varying parameters

Tags: ios, swift, generics

Suppose I have a function that accepts a callback *with a sender*, like this:

```
func performAction(aNumber: Double, completion: (sender: UIButton) -> Void) {
    // Does some stuff here
    let button = getAButtonFromSomewhere()
    completion(button)
}
```

And so one possible way to call this function is by passing *an existing function* for the callback, rather than defining the closure in-place:

```
performAction(10, completion: myCallback)

func myCallback(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.setTitle("foo", forState: .Normal)
}
```

**Back in my definition for `performAction`, how can I define the completion block to accept a `UIButton` or any subclass of it?**

As an example, suppose I have a `UIButton` subclass called `CustomButton`. So in my callback, I'm only interested in accepting a `CustomButton`. I'd like to do this:

```
performAction(10, completion: myCallback)

// This produces a compiler error:
func myCallback(sender: CustomButton) {
    sender.setTitle("foo", forState: .Normal)
}

// This works, but forces me to cast to my custom class:
func myCallback(sender: UIButton) {
    let realButton = sender as! CustomButton
    realButton.setTitle("foo", forState: .Normal)
}
```

But the compiler won't allow it, because the definition of `performAction` requires the callback to accept a `UIButton` specifically (even though `CustomButton` *is* a `UIButton` subclass).

I'd like `performAction` to be generic so that it can be packaged in a library, and work with any `UIButton` subclass. Is this possible to do in Swift?

**EDIT:** I tried to simplify what I'm doing with the example above, but I think it just caused confusion. Here's the actual code that I'm trying to make work, with some improvements thanks to @luk2302:

```
public extension UIButton {

    private class Action: AnyObject {
        private var function: Any
        init(function: Any) {
            self.function = function
        }
    }

    // Trickery to add a stored property to UIButton...
    private static var actionsAssocKey: UInt8 = 0

    private var action: Action? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &UIButton.actionsAssocKey) as? Action
        }
        set(newValue) {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &UIButton.actionsAssocKey, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        }
    }

    internal func performAction(sender: UIButton) {
        if let function = self.action!.function as? () -> Void {
            function()
        // THIS IS WHERE THINGS BREAK NOW:
        } else if let function = self.action!.function as? (sender: self.Type) -> Void {
            function(sender: self)
        }
    }

    public func addTarget(forControlEvents event: UIControlEvents, action: () -> Void) {
        self.action = Action(function: action)
        self.addTarget(self, action: "performAction:", forControlEvents: event)
    }

    public func addTarget<B: UIButton>(forControlEvents: UIControlEvents, actionWithSender: (sender: B) -> Void) {
        self.action = Action(function: actionWithSender)
        self.addTarget(self, action: "performAction:", forControlEvents: forControlEvents)
    }
}
```

The only piece that breaks now is the line that I commented, at `(sender: self.Type)` (`self` being either `UIButton`, or some subclass of it).

So this deviates from my original question slightly, but how can I can I cast `function` to a closure accepting a sender of the same type as `self`? This code works perfectly if I hard-code the type, but it should be able to work for *any* `UIButton` subclass.

Comment: How does the mythical `getAButtonFromSomewhere()` actually work?

Comment: @jtbandes It was just an example so I don't have to post my entire implementation here. For the sake of the question, we can safely assume that it always returns a `CustomButton`, or whatever class the user is expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the UIButton subclass a **generic parameter** for the `performAction` function, but then you will need to cast the button *before* passing it to the callback, unless you also have a generic way of "getting" the right type of button.

```
// performAction() works with any type of UIButton
func performAction<B: UIButton>(aNumber: Double, completion: (sender: B) -> Void)
{
    // Assuming getAButtonFromSomewhere returns UIButton, and not B, you must cast it.
    if let button = getAButtonFromSomewhere() as? B {
        completion(sender: button)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself this: what should happen if you pass a closure of type `(CustomButton -> Void)` as `completion` and then `getAButtonFromSomewhere` returns an instance of `UIButton`? The code then cannot invoke the closure since the `UIButton` is not a `CustomButton`.

The compiler simply does not allow you to pass `(CustomButton -> Void)` to `(UIButton -> Void)` because `(CustomButton -> Void)` is more restrictive than `(UIButton -> Void)`. Note that you can pass `(UIButton -> Void)` to a closure of type `(CustomButton -> Void)` since `(UIButton -> Void)` is *less* restrictive - you can pass everything you pass to the first to the second as well.

Therefore either make `func` use a generic type as @jtbandes suggests or use your initial approach a little bit improved:

```
func myCallback(sender: UIButton) {
    if let realButton = sender as? CustomButton {
        realButton.setTitle("foo", forState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

Both solutions will result in the `setTitle` to not be invoked whenever the returned value of `getAButtonFromSomewhere` is not a `CustomButton`.

Comment: `getAButtonFromSomewhere` isn't actually real - I just used that for the sake of the question. In the actual implementation we're guaranteed that `button` is always the type we're looking for. But from your explanation, it makes sense that the compiler can't know that for sure.

Comment: @hundley *how* can you be sure? If you really can be sure, why is the closure defined to accept a `UIButton` in the first place and not a `CustomButton`?

Comment: See my edit to the original question. Any idea how to solve this last tiny issue?